# Configure Bonding with DHCP

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp, bonding

I'm trying to use bonding in active-passive mode, with 2 ethernet interfaces. I'd like the system to be always connected to the network, while there is at least one cable connected. I must be able to use this system with a DHCP server.

For now, I didn't find any working answer on the internet, so now I'm asking you guys :)

PinkPR

Answer (score 3):

From the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt), this configuration has worked for me in the past (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Define primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1

# Define secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    # delay ifup to allow eth0 to come up first in the bond
    pre-up sleep 2
    bond-master bond0
    bond-primary eth0 eth1

# Define master bond interface with link local address.
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    bond-slaves none
    bond-mode active-backup
    bond-miimon 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
$/etc/modprobe.d/somefile

alias bond0 bonding   
options bonding mode=1 arp_interval=1000 

$/etc/network/interfaces 

auto bond0  
iface bond0 inet manual  
   up ifconfig bond0 up    
   up ifenslave bond0 eth0 eth1  
   up dhclient3 -e IF_METRIC=100 -pf /var/run/dhclient.bond0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.bond0.leases bond0  
   down ifenslave -d bond0 eth0 eth1
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I don't have dhclient3. I have dhclient, which is in version 4.3.1, and has no option -e. What would be the equivalent for dhclient ?

Comment: Hello , on isc-dhclient 4.3.3 there is option e :

Comment: -e VAR=value
              Define additional environment variables for the environment where dhclient-script executes.  You may specify multiple -e options on the command line.